# Haskell аппликативный или нормальный?

Tags: haskell, sicp

Я изучаю язык Haskell и параллельно читаю SICP. В SICP нашёл следующее.
Бен Битобор (согласно книге SICP) придумал тест для проверки интерпретатора на то, с каким порядком вычислений он работает, аппликативным или нормальным. Бен определяет такие две процедуры:

```
(define (p) (p))
(define (test x y) (if (= x 0) 0 y))
```

Затем он вычисляет выражение:

```
(test 0 (p))
```

Если результатом является 0, то интерпретатор - нормальный, если впадает в вычисление "p" - аппликативный. Согласно теста язык Scheme является аппликативным.
Я переписал проверку под Haskell для интерпретатора GHCi:

```
let p = p
let test x y = if (x == 0) then 0 else y
test 0 p
```

Результатом получил 0.
Правильно ли я применил тест Битобора, результатом которого является факт, что Haskell (GHCi) является нормальным языком программирования? Равносильно ли это понятию "ленивые вычисления"?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Всё правильно

Да, Haskell в терминах этой книги *нормальный*.

...и речь действительно идёт о **ленивых вычислениях**, а именно ленивом вычислении аргументов функции при её вызове. Термина *нормальный* стоит в этом контексте избегать ввиду его излишней общности и распространённости в самых разных областях, термин *ленивый* куда осмысленнее.

Первая процедура — очевидная "рекурсивная бомба", которая вешает выполнение программы при попытке вызова (если нет оптимизации хвостовой рекурсии, то ещё и уронит программу). Поэтому весь тест упирается в то, будет ли вычислен второй аргумент независимо от того, потребует ли его значения функция в процессе выполнения.

Внимание стоит обратить лишь на ту деталь, что **нельзя просто так выкинуть вторую процедуру** и заинлайнить её вызов в её реализации как-то так:

```
(if (= 0 0) 0 (p))
```

...потому что `if` в лиспах обычно является *особой формой* (special form), а не функцией, а потому имеет другой порядок вычислений, чем для вызовов функций.